# Get one query using two tables

Tags: php, sql

I want to get details from two table in my database.I use following code

```
$sqlall="SELECT 
       student_detail.reg_no
      , student_detail.full_Name
      , student_detail.year_of_study
      , student_detail.faculty
      , student_detail.course
      ,student_hostel.reg_no
      ,student_hostel.room_no
      ,student_hostel.hostel_id 
  FROM student_detail,student_hostel 
  WHERE student_detail.reg_no = student_hostel.reg_no; ";


//This is print part
$result = $conn->query($sqlall);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    //create table

    echo "<table class=\"table table-hover\">
        <tr>
        <th>Reg. No.</th><th>Hostel id</th><th>Room No</th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo"<tr id=\"".$row["student_detail.reg_no"]."\" onclick=\"Redirect(this.id)\"><td>".$row["student_detail.reg_no"]."</td><td>".$row["student_hostel.room_no"]."</td><td>".$row["student_hostel.room_no"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<table class=\"table table-hover\">
            <tr>
            <th>Reg. No.</th><th>Hostel id</th><th>Room No</th></tr>;
            <span id></span>
            </table>";
    }
```

**after going to get data then an error occurred**

> Notice: Undefined index: student_detail.reg_no in C:\xampp\htdocs\HMS\HMS\lib\HOS_current.php on line 47

How can I fix it?

Comment: You will have to post more than that then

Comment: please just echo the row without the table name `echo $row['reg_no'];`

Comment: edit the question with the code when you run the query and how u display it

Comment: Updated my answer please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY THIS:**

```
 $sqlall="SELECT student_detail.reg_no, student_detail.full_Name, student_detail.year_of_study, student_detail.faculty, student_detail.course,student_hostel.reg_no,student_hostel.room_no,student_hostel.hostel_id FROM student_detail INNER JOIN student_hostel ON student_detail.reg_no=student_hostel.reg_no; ";
```

Comment: **Try This** does not really help the OP understand what he did wrong

Answer (score 2):

**I would suggest that you use sql joins, SQL joins are used to combine rows from two or more tables.**

This is how to achieve what you want with joins

```
 $sqlall = "SELECT DISTINCT student_detail.reg_no, student_detail.full_Name, student_detail.year_of_study, student_detail.faculty, student_detail.course,student_hostel.reg_no,student_hostel.room_no,student_hostel.hostel_id FROM student_detail inner join student_hostel on student_hostel.reg_no
    = student_detail.reg_no";
$result = $conn->query($sqlall);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    //create table

    echo "<table class=\"table table-hover\">
        <tr>
        <th>Reg. No.</th><th>Hostel id</th><th>Room No</th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo"<tr id=\"".$row["reg_no"]."\" onclick=\"Redirect(this.id)\"><td>".$row["reg_no"]."</td><td>".$row["room_no"]."</td><td>".$row["room_no"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<table class=\"table table-hover\">
            <tr>
            <th>Reg. No.</th><th>Hostel id</th><th>Room No</th></tr>;
            <span id></span>
            </table>";
    }
?>
```

In the above I have used `inner join`

> The INNER JOIN keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as
>   there is a match between the columns in both tables.

The basic syntax for this join is:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

or

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

> **NB: INNER JOIN is the same as JOIN.**

NB: When you printout the results, don't `echo $row['tableName.ColumnName'];`  just echo out `$row['ColumnName'];`

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong single quote at the beginning for student_detail.reg_no  change it with a backtics

You have a wrong single quote at the beginning for student_detail.reg_no  change it with a backtics
ad the bakctics should wrap table and column  distincly 
and you have backtics arount the tow tables  too

```
$sqlall="SELECT 
          `student_detail`.`reg_no`
          , `student_detail`.`full_Name`
          , `student_detail`.`year_of_study`
          , `student_detail`.`faculty`
          , `student_detail`.`course`
          ,`student_hostel`.`reg_no`
          ,`student_hostel`.`room_no`
          ,`student_hostel`.`hostel_id` 
      FROM student_detail,student_hostel
      WHERE `student_detail`.`reg_no` = `student_hostel`.`reg_no`; ";
```

or, due the fact that you have not reserved  word or space, don't use backics in this case

```
$sqlall="SELECT 
          student_detail.reg_no 
          , student_detail.full_Name
          , student_detail.year_of_study
          , student_detail.faculty
          , student_detail.course
          ,student_hostel.reg_no
          ,student_hostel.room_no
          ,student_hostel.hostel_id 
      FROM student_detail,student_hostel 
      WHERE student_detail.reg_no = student_hostel.reg_no; ";
```

for the second error do the fatc you are in while loop  mean the query  should return rows .. so the error could be related to the column name  ... try (for test) using an alias  eg:

```
SELECT 
          student_detail.reg_no as no
          .....
```

and refer to you column in while loop this way

```
echo"<tr id=\"".$row['no']."\" onclick=\"Redirect(this.id)\"><td>".$row['no'].
         "</td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
```

Comment: @JohnHC   . i have alraedy see .. i have update  the answer .. anyway  many thanks for suggestion

Comment: `echo"<tr id=\"".$row["student_detail.reg_no"]."\" onclick=\"Redirect(this.id)\"><td>".$row["student_detail.reg_no"]."</td><td>".$row["student_hostel.room_no"]."</td><td>".$row["student_hostel.room_no"]."</td></tr>";
  }`       **Notice: Undefined index: student_detail.reg_no in C:\xampp\htdocs\HMS\HMS\lib\HOS_current.php on line 47**

Comment: the code you provided in question  is only for sql .query but . the comment if for the result  .. so you should update your question and add also the code for render the result..

Comment: @RUC...   i have update the answer  with some suggestion hope are useful

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$sqlall= "
SELECT student_detail.reg_no, 
       student_detail.full_Name, 
       student_detail.year_of_study, 
       student_detail.faculty,
       student_detail.course,
       student_hostel.reg_no,
       student_hostel.room_no,
       student_hostel.hostel_id 
FROM student_detail
INNER JOIN student_hostel 
ON student_detail.reg_no = student_hostel.reg_no;";
```

See the ANSI JOIN syntax? Also, bad backticks and apostophes in orginal code

If you *really* have to use backticks, use them around each entity:

```
`student_detail`.`reg_no`
```